# How can I test if my dependent variable increases or decreases from one year to another?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset called `data` , which contains data on `contaminant`, my dependent variable. All observations in one year are independent from the following years.
My predictors are `Species` (three levels) and `Year` (three levels): Basically, I need to see if there is an increase/decrease in the contaminant data over time for each species separately.

So far I tried this code

```
    model1<- lm(contaminant~Species*Year,data=data)

            #using Year as numerical (covariate): Indeed, I do not care about 
            the difference in contaminants load among species in each year. 
            I simply want to test if the slopes of each species are significant.
```

**1st Question**: I am doing that correctly by treating Year as a number? Or is there another specific way/code to treat time series? I actually want to have a p-value that tells me that Series1 in the graph below (made with average values of each group) had a significant increase over time. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfIfb.png)

My summary output looks like this:

```
Call: lm(formula = Contaminant ~ Species * Year, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.1135 -1.3595 -0.1475  1.3225  7.3652 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    -588.6625   996.6024  -0.591 0.556036    
Species2       -823.3590  1320.9209  -0.623 0.534451    
Species3      -4798.0032  1393.0990  -3.444 0.000830 ***
Year              0.2930     0.4941   0.593 0.554484    
Species2:Year     0.4092     0.6549   0.625 0.533462    
Species3:Year     2.3802     0.6907   3.446 0.000824 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.21 on 103 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3853,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3555 
F-statistic: 12.91 on 5 and 103 DF,  p-value: 9.428e-10
```

**2nd Question:** Why is my summary output giving me only two interactions? Why it does not provide also Species1:Year?

**3rd Question:** Does anybody knows how to make a graph like this in r? So far I am only able to do that in excel using mean values of each group

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If your observations include only whole years and not full dates, it is fine to add the year as a variable. As long as you do not convert it to a factor, it assumes per year a constant increase.

2) Dummy - or one-hot - Encoding always tests the difference of groups to a baseline group. That means S2 tests S2-S1, and S3 tests S3-S1. The same is valid for the interaction terms.

3) There are multiple possibilities, but it will be more than 1-2 lines of code. See e.g. http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/#line-graphs-1

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I actually have specific dates (dd/mm/yy), would that be better to run a model with those? If so how should I do?                                                And following your answer to question 2, so 0.29 is the slope for Species 1?

Comment: 1) If you use dates, you assume a constant small change per day. If you use years, you assume a constant change per increase of +1 in the calendar year. Use as.POSIXct() or as.Date() for conversion. 

2) -588 is the base for species 1. For species 2 the estimate is then  -599 - 823. Sure, the estimate only makes sense after addding also the other factors! Use predict() to get useful estimates for your observations.